# Android App crashes when installed from website/Google Drive

Tags: android, download, crash, apk

I made an app recently for a friend and I tested it out on my phone connected to Android Studio and it worked perfectly. But when I uploaded it to my Google Drive for them to download it, it crashed whenever a button was pressed. (Unfortunately [App name} has stopped). Someone help, thanks.

UPDATE: Since I've been told to add more detail, here's some more detail:

- The APK is signed
- The app installs perfectly, it loads the mainActivity and then once any button on activity is pressed, it gives an error saying "Unfortunately, [App name] has stopped.)
- Works perfectly when tested directly from Android studio

Comment: u should provide more detail

Comment: Could you add the LogCat of the crash ? You can find this in Google Play developer console.

Comment: @JonasCz Do you mean in android studio?

Comment: No, in the Google Play developer console (where you uploaded your application), there should be a section with crash reports, you should find it there.

Comment: @JonasCz Oh I don't have a developer account, I simply exported the APK. I probably should get one in order to get those crash reports

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently it was an error in my code, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the sdk version on your friends device is lower than the min sdk you provided in the build file ?
honestly there could be lots of reasons, i need more details..

Comment: It's really odd... nobody else seems to have this problem. So basically the app installs perfectly and the mainActivity loads, but the app crashes (with the message "Unfortunately [App name} has stopped" as soon as any button is pressed. It only works when it's tested directly from my pc from android studio. Not when downloaded off the internet as an APK. The APK is signed if that helps.

Comment: did you test the download ask on other devices ?

Comment: @EyarGofer yes, I asked a couple friends to test it out for me (Nexus 5 and a OnePlus) and it still didn't work.